# Is there an html "mailto:" equivalent for crypto addresses

Tags: html, href, ethereum

I'd like to prime a browser to take special actions on ethereum addresses or tx, potentially opening user's default local client programs, or linking to sites like etherescan.io, etc.

Is there any HTML treatment standard like that of mailto: or sms: for crypto addresses of any kind?

I am explicitly **not** looking to create a **custom** handler, but whether there exists a **standard** handler.  (And that answer may simply be no.)

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=custom+protocol+html

Comment: Re-opened - the answer is no

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67

Comment: A useful reference point is https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-681 -- If that doesn't look right, can you give a different analogy? All the analogies given (mailto, sms) are to *trigger some specific action*: send an email or send an sms. I'm not clear which action you're trying to trigger. Seeing arbitrary metadata about an address, which is a general case of "linking to sites like etherscan", is probably not specific enough to become a standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed.  Per comments, the answer is no.